# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " '\'All\' ' "

Tags: java

I am using MDL discretization method that can be used to discretize the contusion data into discrete data into the following format

```
v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10,v11,v12,v13,v14,v15,class
'\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'(-inf-0.494758]\'',1
'\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'(-inf-0.494758]\'',2
'\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'(-inf-0.494758]\'',1
'\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'(-inf-0.494758]\'',2
'\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'All\'','\'(-inf-0.494758]\'',1
```

when I trying to execute my code I got the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "'\'All\''"   at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at PSOFS.PruningLocalSearch.main(PruningLocalSearch.java:68)
```

My code is

```
BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        int countlines=0;
                try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename1));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] datalines = line.split(",");                
               filefeaturesnumbers = datalines.length;
                for (int df=0;df<datalines.length;df++){
                    String datast = datalines[df];
                    int dataint = Integer.parseInt(datast);
                    datasetMat[countlines][df]=dataint;
                        }
                countlines++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
br.close();
```

the line that cause the error is

```
int dataint = Integer.parseInt(datast);
```

Thank you for all who can possibly help.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` **only** works with actual digits/numbers

Comment: Obviously `All` can't be converted to an integer - what exactly are you trying to do there?

Comment: What number do you expect the string `"All"` to represent?

Comment: Thanks all..Actually All is produced by the MDL discretization method and I need to send the data to mutual information (ML)after I did the discretization because ML cant be used with  the continuous data

Comment: anyone who could to parse this string =>>>"'\'All\''" to int, i will bye to programming area .

Comment: Well, _of course_ `"All"` has the value 42 ;) - seriously, if the value isn't a number then either ignore it or convert it to a number in some way, e.g. by selecting a default value or provinding a mapping like `"All" = 42, "foo" = 1, "bar" = 77` etc. (I just picked random numbers, if you do a mapping then you probably have a better "algorithm" ;) ).

Comment: @sally, `(-inf-0.494758]` is also not an integer number - it's a `double` range at best, from negative infinity to `-0.494758`, presumably. You will have to parse it in a different way than you're doing currently.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I'd assume the upper bound is `0.494758` and is included in the range. :)

Comment: @Thomas, but I've not seen any formats where range bounds will be delimited by something that can also be a part of numeric constant. Usually I delimit them with `, ` (with the space). This is also common in math, so it's recognizable. There are no spaces in that example format.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yes I'd use the comma as well to reduce confusion :) - from a technical point of view I'd still assume there has to be _some_ delimiter or ranges like `[3-5]` would be hard to define. Thus I'd assume that if the upper bound was negative it would be something like `(-inf--0.4...]`. But again that's me from a technical perspective and I might be wrong here :)

Comment: Thanks all for yr reply.@M.Prokhorov Yes i will pay attention about (-inf-0.494758], tust need to get rid of the All first.

Comment: @Thomas, I agree. `-` could be the delimiter there. As for assuming, we might both be wrond, and that's just a user name or any other arbitrary string. The whole thing is also a weird version of the CSV, so-o....

Comment: @sally, I'm not sure you "get rid of it" - it's in your data, so you need to handle it. Since it's clearly a constant, look up what it means in terms of your data source. Maybe it's a shorthand for `(-inf-+inf)` or something, who knows.